# NSInvalidArgumentException Error When Using UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I got the following error and I can't seem to figure out what happened.  Please help me.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x57405a0'

Comment: you are calling a UITableViewControllerDelegate method (numberOfRowsInSection:) on a UIViewController which doesn't implement the protocol. That's about all we can tell you from what you've provided. We need to see how you populate your UITabBarController.

Comment: What do you want me to show? Sorry, I'm new to Objective-C.

Comment: What are you returning from numberOfRowsInSection method ?

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array count];
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using:

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { return [array count]; } –
```

Try:

```
NSLog(@"%i", [array count]);
```

And see what returns. Maybe the array is not been properly allocated.

Answer (score 0):

This could be anything. It might be a delegate being called which does not implement the protocol, or it might be a memory leak where a call is made on some released memory. Hard to tell like this. Try compiling with "Analyze" and check all warnings.

Comment: I don't have any leaks when I run with "Analyze".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but the solution was not associated with the **numberOfRowsInSection**: method as Xcode was pointing too.

Instead, the overriding problem was that I had not set my **UIViewController's Custom 
Class** setting... In my case it was empty instead of having a valid class name like "DetailsVC2" in the example image below. Once I corrected this issue the usual **numberOfRowsInSection:** operation is recognized and called correctly.

Typically, you want to return the count of an array (e.g. tableData), but in my very simple case I returned the value of 1.

```
NSArray *tableData; // Defined somewhere above, and populated prior to the viewDidAppear() operation

 .
 .
 .

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return 1; // or tableData.count;
}
```

[image]